# Make a PNG transparent where color is white and area is not within lines of an object/item?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

I have this image below which at 1 time I had it as a transparent PNG but somewhere down the line I have messed up and saved it with a white background.

I really need to make all the white that is outside the edges of the items to be transparent and still have it have a clean crisp line when shown on top of a colored background.

I can't simply replace all white since the inside items have white as well.  I an a developer and not a graphic person.

How can I fix this image?  Any help please?

[image]

Comment: Do you need a vector image outcome or png only?

Answer (score 2):

**Photoshop - PNG or JPG**

In Photoshop, start with the wand tool (check the contiguous selection dialog before selecting to ensure that not all white is selected.) Hold shift for multiple selections and select the white areas you wish to remove. Delete the white within the selections.

*Fortunately, these are very clean, hard lines and should select accurately*

*If you are looking for a vector, you likely have to recreate it as any trace options aren't going to get you very far*

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to keep the contiguous selection active, select the outside and clear it, and then do the same to the two areas inside of the blue selection frame above and below the book?

Comment: Yeah, when I wrote it, I was trying to simplify for a non PS user, but may have done so poorly. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Simplyfy... heh, more like "How can I dissuade a newbie from trying this, ever" ;)